# In QGIS Atlas how to get the index and the number of features grouped/filtered by an Attribute with expression?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, atlas, qgsexpression

Using a QGIS Expression in the Layout Editor, how can one return the count of features matching a particular attribute value for an atlas feature, for example, "AREAS_Area".

In this particular example, the valid range of values for "Areas_Area" is 1-25.
I would like to return the count of features matching the "Areas_Area" attributes for 1, 2, 3, etc.

Here is what I have currently, which provides me with an index (current Area number out of total Area numbers), as well as the page count (current feature number out of total number of features).

```
concat('Area: ',"Areas_AREA",' / ',maximum("Areas_AREA"),' | ','Segment: ',@atlas_featurenumber,' / ',@atlas_totalfeatures)
```

Image preview:
[image: Image showing rendered expression. Reads "Area: 1 / 25 | Segment: 1 / 777"]

So given the above information and the result I have in the preview, my expectation would be that it would instead read something more like:
Area: 1 / 25 | Segment: 1 / 13

Answer (score 2):

You want to get two information dynamically in your atlas.

#### Get the index of the current segment within the group of segment with the same  `Areas_AREA`

You have to use an id that is unique for this operation. I would use `RIN` for this but you can replace it with any id you have for your segment as long as it is in the same order that your atlas is ordered. You can use the formula `array_agg()` to get an array (kind of list) of all the `RIN` of segment that have  `Areas_AREA` equal to `Areas_AREA` of your current segment. Then you can use `array_find()` to get the index of your current segment inside this array. You have to add +1 because the first element of an array have index 0.

```
array_find(array_agg("RIN", filter:="Areas_AREA"=attribute (@atlas_feature,'Areas_AREA'),"RIN") +1
```

OR a calculation with more explicit values :

```
array_find ( aggregate( @atlas_layername, aggregate:='array_agg', expression:="RIN", filter:="Areas_AREA" =attribute (@atlas_feature ,'Areas_AREA')), "RIN" )+1
```

*The result should be 1 for the first segment then 2 then 3, then when your segment is in another area it should start from 1 again.*

#### The number of segment that have the same `Areas_AREA`

To get the number of segment that have the same area id you can use the formula `count()` number of feature with `Areas_AREA` equal with the attribute `Areas_AREA` of your current atlas feature :

```
count(1, filter:="Areas_AREA" =attribute (@atlas_feature ,'Areas_AREA'))
```

*The result should be a number equal to the number of feature for each area*

Or you can also use array like before and use formula

```
array_length(array_agg("RIN", filter:="Areas_AREA"=attribute (@atlas_feature,'Areas_AREA'))
```

The final formula would be something like :

```
concat('Area: ',"Areas_AREA",' / ',maximum("Areas_AREA"),' | ','Segment: ', 
array_find (aggregate( @atlas_layername, aggregate:='array_agg', expression:="RIN", filter:="Areas_AREA" =attribute (@atlas_feature ,'Areas_AREA')), "RIN" )+1, 
'/',
count(1, filter:="Areas_AREA" =attribute (@atlas_feature ,'Areas_AREA')))
```

Note : To make atlas of atlas the report function could be useful and could add title page for each group of segment with specific maps.

Comment: For my case, "RIN" is my uniqueID field, so I've substituted that for fid.

However, your formula throws the following errors:  

Parser Errors:
All parameters following a named parameter must also be named.
syntax error, unexpected COMMA, expecting $end
syntax error, unexpected COMMA, expecting $end
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end

Comment: Wich version of qgis have you ? Have you tried the first and the second formula and what are the result ? Have you tried to delete the line jump in the last formula (sometimes the copy paste of line jump could be seen as character) ?

Comment: QGIS 3.18.3 x64 for Windows 10.  

The first expression evaluates properly, returning a value of 37 as the count for Feature #2.  

The second formula does not evaluate, and gives the error messages I posted above.

Yes, I've cleaned/stripped the copy/paste code in VSCode and there are no other line-break or other special whitespace characters present.

Comment: Thanks for the version I use 3.18.1 so it is not so far... If the first formula with array work well for you I have added a formula with array to get the count. Can you share the ordering formula you use for your atlas ?  Have you tried to add your formula without verification from the expression editor ?

Comment: The array_find formulas fail, but the array_length and count work just fine.

Atlas Sort By:  
trim(concat("Areas_AREA_STR", '-', "CAMPRS_Name",'-',"CAMPRS_Segment"))

Comment: What is the result of this formula for atlas page : `array_to_string (array_agg("RID", filter:="Areas_AREA"=attribute (@atlas_feature,'Areas_AREA'))`  is your RID of current feature present in the list ? Does this array change when your segment is in another Areas_AREA ?

Comment: Thanks for the continued assistance!

That returns an empty string/array of ''

Comment: And if you try  `array_to_string (array_agg("RID"))` is the result the same that `array_to_string ( aggregate( @atlas_layername, aggregate:='array_agg', expression:="RID"))` ? If it work can you add after "RID" `, filter:="Areas_AREA" =attribute (@atlas_feature ,'Areas_AREA')`

Comment: array_to_string (array_agg("RIN")) seems to return the RINs as a comma separated list.

array_to_string ( aggregate...)) also seems to return a comma separated list.

array_to_string (aggregate(...))) with the extra filter statement also seems to properly return a comma separated list.

Comment: Ok, so may be it work better with aggregate. Try `array_find ( aggregate( @atlas_layername, aggregate:='array_agg', expression:="RIN", filter:="Areas_AREA" =attribute (@atlas_feature ,'Areas_AREA')), "RIN" )+1` it should give you the current RIN index among the RIN in the areas area.

Comment: Awesome! This returns numbers, but I can't figure out exactly what they are. They don't seem to be the page's position within that group for that atlas number.

For instance, Page 1 (Area 1/25) reads 28, Page 2 (Area 1/25) reads 22, Page 3 (Area 1/25) reads 9, etc. Area 1 has 37 Pages to it.

Comment: RIN field is number or not ? Can you try to order your atlas based on RIN and check it work ? may be share in your post a part of your attribute table for field "Areas_AREA", "Areas_AREA_STR", "CAMPRS_Name", "CAMPRS_Segment", "RIN"

Comment: Sorry, Corentin, but you are right, RIN is not a real/integer, it is a string field.

Comment: It should work as well with string. After thinking the order should not be set first to verify it work. And then when the result is what we expect we will find a way to get the same order in the expression array and in the atlas.